# Converting 4 dimensional tensors into list of lists of lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor

I have 6 tensors of shape (batch_size, S, S, 1) and I want to combine them in one python list of size (batch_size, S*S, 6) - so every element of tensor should be inside the inner list.

Can this be achieved without using loops? What's the efficient way to solve it?

Comment: My initial idea to solve this problem is to use `pytorch.cat` to make one tensor of size (batch_size, S, S, 6) and then somehow reduce the dimensions. However, I have no clue how to diminish the number of dimensions and still ensure that no values are missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `batch_size=10` and `S=4` for the purpose of this example:

```
 >>> x = [torch.rand(10, 4, 4, 1) for _ in range(6)]
```

Indeed the first step is to concatenate the tensor on the last dimension `axis=3`:

```
>>> y = torch.cat(x, -1)
>>> y.shape
torch.Size([10, 4, 4, 6])
```

Then reshape to flatten `axis=1` and `axis=2`, you can do so with [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html) here since the two axes as adjacent:

```
>>> y = torch.cat(x, -1).flatten(1, 2)
>>> y.shape
torch.Size([10, 16, 6])
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply, this solves the issue.